# Spring security failing to block the URLs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have the following scenario where I have to allow only a particular URL and deny others. But I am not sure why its allowing both URLs

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        try{
            return http
                    .requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/RemoteHandlerServices/Handle"))
                        .authorizeHttpRequests(r -> r
                            .antMatchers("/RemoteHandlerServices/Handle").authenticated())
                    .requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/OtherHandlerServices/Test"))
                        .authorizeHttpRequests(r -> r
                            .antMatchers("/OtherHandlerServices/Test").denyAll()
                            .anyRequest().denyAll()
                    )
                    .build();

    } catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Authentication is failed");
        }
    }
```

Could someone explain me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to substitute your *filterChain* with this one:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(url -> url
            .antMatchers("/RemoteHandlerServices/Handle").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/OtherHandlerServices/Test").denyAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated());
return http.build();
```

**Pay attention** that from Spring Security 5.8 the *antMatchers* (with some others) method has been deprecated and you should use [requestMatchers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-requestmatchers). From Spring Security 6 they have been removed.

Remember that, by default, the first matching filter is the one that is applied to the url, so the next ones are discard.

Here are some useful links: [security filters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-security-filters), [httpsecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#jc-httpsecurity), [java config spring security](https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security)

Answer (score 1):

In current implementation i see some missconfiguration and also some deprecated things and based on it I suggest you to have a look at [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)

Also to get what you want you should replace current one body method to next one:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeHttpRequests(requestMatcherRegistry -> {
            requestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/RemoteHandlerServices/Handle")
                .authenticated();
            requestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest().denyAll();
           });
       return http.build();
    }
```

Short summary about it:
Every request to `/RemoteHandlerServices/Handle` should be `authenticated`
and any others path requests will be denied.

To have more details how it work you have to read/check [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/getting-spring-security.html)